# Update words(size change or remove words) in D3 word cloud without changing their position?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, updates, tag-cloud, word-cloud

I am using the word cloud library in D3 by Jason Davies. This is the normal code which I am using and works fine for creating the word clouds.

```
    d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
            .words(d3.zip(vis_words, vis_freq).map(function(d) {
                                    return {text: d[0], size: wordScale(d[1]) };
                                    }))
            .padding(1)
            .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 0; })
            .font("times")
            .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
            .on("end", draw)
            .start();

    function draw(words) {
            d3.select(curr_id).append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," +  height/2 + ")")
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .data(words)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d,i){
                                    return i*100;
                                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .ease("elastic")
                    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                    .style("font-family", "times")
                    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                                    })
                    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }
```

I have a time slider to select a specific value, based on which words in the word cloud have different frequency(given by size) or some of the words are not there at all. I need to update without redrawing the entire word cloud which I am currently doing. In a way, I want to keep the position of words fixed and just updating their size and whether they exist based on the value selected on a slider?

Should I enter an update function in the function draw for this? Am certainly new to D3 and any help would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you would select the existing `text` elements and set the `font-size` property for them. The code to do this looks like this:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("text")
  .style("font-size", function(d, i) { // do something });
```

Comment: One warning, though: if this increases the size of the words they may end up overlapping.  If you don't want that to happen, calculate the original layout of words based on the maximum possible size for each, then adjust the size (or visibility) based on your slider value.  You may have lots of extra whitespace, but that is probably better than overlapping.

Comment: @Lars Thanks for the comment, but as in the code snippet shared above, I am already setting the font-size property.

Comment: @AmeliaBR I did remove the attr("transform", "***") which translates the words to their new location so that they stay there, but then there are obvious overlaps. The main issue in my case is that the function which even calls the layout to calculate the word size and draws the word cloud is to be called again and again, then how can I calculate the original layout of words based on the maximum possible size of each?

Comment: @Anuj If you don't want to set the font size, what do you want to do?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Please read the comment above. I want to modify the size of the words which is happening based on the wordScale I have chosen. But passing the words through the layout recalculated the position of the words, which I want to avoid. Removing the .attr("transform", ***), does help me in not changing the word locations but when new words are added or some words exit on moving the slider, there are obvious overlaps. Trying to prevent those overlaps. Hope this helps :).

Comment: Well it sounds like you would have to rerun the layout. There's no guarantee that you'll be able to scale the words to their new sizes without moving them or any overlap. If you take the maximum size (for which you would have to set the max value for each word before running the layout), you'll end up with a lot of empty space in most cases.